# How user, database and schema are related in Teradata?

Tags: database, teradata, rdbms

I am aware of Oracle. In oracle schema or user is more or less same. When we create a user, schema is created.

Database is something we create when we install oracle.

I am new to Teradata. Are things same in case of Teradata too?

How **user**, **database** and **schema** are related in Teradata?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full Teradata **system** is quite similar to a **database** in Oracle.

A **database** in Teradata is the same as a **schema** in Oracle.

A **user** is almost the same as a **database** in Teradata ( you can create objects in both), the main difference is the ability to logon to the system.

And there's a hierarchy of users & databases in Teradata, root is user `dbc`. Users might own databases and databases might own users. A user has the implicit right to manage his children (i.e. `GRANT` & `REVOKE` access rights on owned databases & users).

End users are usually a leaf in the hierarchy, no children & no perm space to store tables.

For more details see: [About Databases and Users in Teradata](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_10/index.html#page/Database_Management/B035_1093_151K/1093Chap2.026.01.html)

Comment: and dnoeth what about schema in teradata?

Comment: @devツ: Theres no `schema` in Teradata, the closest you get is a `database`.

Comment: Hi @dnoeth, in nowadays it exist?  see https://teradata.github.io/presto/docs/0.167-t/sql/create-schema.html

Comment: @PeterKrauss: No, your link is for Presto, not Teradata.